# Do I need to seed any random number generator before using EVP_PKEY_keygen of OpenSSL?

Tags: encryption, openssl, public-key-encryption, public-key, encryption-asymmetric

On the OpenSSL Wiki page called [EVP Key and Parameter Generation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Key_and_Parameter_Generation) it states the following:

> Since these functions use random numbers you should ensure that the random number generator is appropriately seeded

But nowhere on [EVP_PKEY_keygen](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_PKEY_keygen.html) does it make mention of seeding a random number generator. It only discusses the low-level doc pages for non-EVP functions for generating keys.

I have also searched and everywhere no mention is made of seeding when the EVP functions are used.

So my question is; May I assume that the seeding is done internally for me in the higher-level EVP functions?

If I do need to do it then which functions must I have a look at?

Comment: The pages you cited are part of the `man` pages. I don't think I can have them refer to the wiki. So your issue might go unaddressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but nowhere on https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_PKEY_keygen.html it makes any mention of seeding a random number generator....

See the OpenSSL wiki page [Random Numbers](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Random_Numbers). It takes you through it in grueling detail.

---

> ... no mention is made of seeding when the EVP functions are used

The EVP functions use whatever generator is in use for the library. It could be `md_rand` or a FIPS AES/CTR generator. There's nothing special to get random numbers for the EVP functions (as opposed to other functions).

---

> May I assume that the seeding is done internally for me in the higher-level EVP functions?

Yes, *if* you did not seed the generator yourself. If you seeded the generator and there's sufficient entropy, then it will not auto-seed itself.

You should avoid allowing the generator to auto-seed itself. See the OpenSSL wiki page [Random Numbers](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Random_Numbers) for the details.

There's nothing special about seeding/auto-seeding a generator when using EVP interfaces. Whatever you do applies to everything.

---

> If I do need to do it then which functions must I have a look at?

The OpenSSL wiki page [Random Numbers](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Random_Numbers) provides more details, but you should do something like:

```
int rc = RAND_load_file("/dev/urandom", 32);
if(rc != 32) {
    /* RAND_load_file failed */
}

/* OK to proceed */
```

You want to avoid a direct call to `RAND_poll`, and you want to avoid auto-seeding (which calls `RAND_poll` internally).

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. Just a pity Firefox cannot connect to wiki.openssl.org as it is considered untrusted.

Comment: What about when calling RAND_load_file on a Windows OS? Which file should be used? Do you know about "A million random digits"? Would that file be a good file to load?

Comment: @Blurry - looking at the code in `<openssl srcs>/crypto/rand/win_rand.c`, that looks like problem code (I'm pretty sure it suffers the Heap Walk bug). In this case, read 32 bytes via Windows' `CryptGenRandom` and add it to the generator with `RAND_add`. See the [pseudo-random number generator](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/rand.html) documentation.

Comment: After I intially did a seed of the RAND and did the keygen, do I need to do RAND_write_file to create another file which will be loaded with RAND_load_file the next time I generate a key again?

Comment: @Blurry - yes, you can.