# How does the OpenSSL‘s PRNG works in Windows?

Tags: random, openssl

Every time I call `RAND_bytes` and `RAND_pseudo_bytes`, with the same seed, it returns different random numbers and I don't understand why. It said that the PRNG automatically seeds itself from `/dev/urandom` in Linux, but how does it work in  Windows?

Why does the same seed lead to different random numbers?

Comment: See [Random Numbers](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Random_Numbers) on the OpenSSL wiki, [Making openssl generate deterministic key](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22759465/608639) and [Do I need to seed any random number generator before using EVP_PKEY_keygen of OpenSSL?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28537832/608639)

Comment: @jww -Thank you for your help.If you have given a seed,it still automatically seeds itself ?I mean in which condition does it automatically seeds itself (call RAND_poll)

Answer (score -1):

> Why does the same seed lead to different random numbers?

You can read about the general design of the rand subsystem at [Random Numbers](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Random_Numbers) on the OpenSSL wiki. The reason the same seed produces different random numbers is...

It depends on the generator. If you are using the default generator, then you are using `md_rand`. If you look at the [source code for `md_rand.c`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/rand/md_rand.c), then you will see `rand_bytes` adds entropy at each invocation with system calls to functions like `time`.

On Linux `rand_bytes` also adds the result of `getpid`; and on Windows it adds the result of `GetSystemTime` and `SystemTimeToFileTime`.

Adding entropy at each invocation is a good design practice for RNGs. Also see [When Good Randomness Goes Bad: Virtual Machine Reset Vulnerabilities
and Hedging Deployed Cryptography](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rist/papers/sslhedge.pdf) and [When Virtual is Harder than Real: Security Challenges in Virtual Machine Based Computing Environments](http://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/hotos05/final_papers/full_papers/garfinkel/garfinkel.pdf).

Comment: @Xiphogod - Please look at the source code to [`md_rand.c`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/rand/md_rand.c). It calls functions like "get process id" and "get time". It stirs the generator each time `RAND_bytes` is called.

Comment: I have looked at the source code for rand_bytes,I only found that
 if (!initialized)
  {
  RAND_poll();
  initialized = 1;
  } Does it add entropy with the RAND_poll?

Comment: @Xiphogod - The lettering in a blue font is a hyperlink. Follow the link for [`md_rand.c`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/rand/md_rand.c) and search for `time_t curr_time = time(NULL);`.

Comment: Thank you very much.I find them in a later version.

Comment: At first,I use openssl 0.9.8o ,I can't find add time seed in RAND_bytes,it only add pid,but the same seed also lead to different random numbers.(I try on windows)

Comment: @Xiphogod - It sounds like you are on OS X, not Windows. If you are on OS X, then you will want to upgrade to get Elliptic Curve and TLS 1.2 goodies. Also see [Homebrew refusing to link OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38670295), [Update OpenSSL on OS X with Homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15185661), [How to install latest version of openssl Mac OS X El Capitan](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35129977), [How to upgrade OpenSSL in OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126830), [Openssl installation using HomeBrew fails](http://superuser.com/q/486389), etc.